# Ansible lineinfile Regex

Tags: regex, ansible

I have this text

```
[john]
age=20
group=wheel
[doe]
age=30
group=wheel
[stack]
age=undefined
group=wheel
color=white
[overflow]
age=undefined
```

and i want to capture with first regex:

```
age=20
```

and **group=wheel** of [stack] with the second one

Comment: [`/\[john\].*?(age=\d+).*\[stack\].*?(group=[^\r\n]+)/gs`](https://regex101.com/r/kEpfmf/1) would give you the `$1` and `$2` which you seek

Comment: thank you for your reply, but with ansible i can't choose $1 and $2, it take full match, for this reason i need 2 different regex that full match the regex.

Comment: Does Ansible support `\K`?

Comment: Ansible use python regex (https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).
I think python doesn't have  \K but i'm not sure about that.

Comment: Python does not support `\K` indeed. You're out of luck. You can't use capture groups, `\K` is not supported, and a distant third option of using variable length lookbehinds is also not supported. There is no way to cleanly retrieve your desired results. Actually, `age=20` is doable but `group=wheel` is not.

Comment: Thank you anyway for your help, i really appreciated it.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use regex for a well defined text file format; the [`ini` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/lookup/ini.html) is what you are actually after:

```
# assuming the ini file is /tmp/foo.ini
tasks:
- set_fact:
    john_age: '{{ lookup("ini", "age section=john file=/tmp/foo.ini") }}'
    stack_group: '{{ lookup("ini", "group section=stack file=/tmp/foo.ini") }}'
```

then, in the case where your content isn't actually in a file, it seems the lookup only works with *files* so you'd need to temporarily write it out to a file:

```
tasks:
- copy:
    dest: /tmp/foo.ini
    content: '{{ the_ini_from_your_question_goes_here }}'
- set_fact:
    john_age: '{{ lookup("ini", "age section=john file=/tmp/foo.ini") }}'
    stack_group: '{{ lookup("ini", "group section=stack file=/tmp/foo.ini") }}'
- file:
    path: /tmp/foo.ini
    state: absent
```

Comment: at the end i solved using ini_file (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ini_file_module.html) it allow me to don't worry at all about regex

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you were trying to extract the information, not mutate it. But either way, I'm glad you used a module designed for working with ini files rather than regexing them :)